# How can I print the current directory exactly as zsh displays it in the prompt?

Tags: shell, zsh

I use zsh shell, with the `%1~` parameter inside my prompt. Instead of displaying `/home/username` it displays `~`, `/home/username/Desktop` changes to just `Desktop`.

I need to get the length of the prompt-displayed path programmatically, ie `~` would amount to just 1 character, while `/home/username` would use 14. Is there a way to do it without overcomplicating stuff?

Comment: Do you mean `print -P '%1~'`?

Comment: I guess I wouldn't be able to mark it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Well, it's a bit unclear what you want. On the one hand, it seems you want to get the prompt string (which that `print` command gives you); on the other it seems you want the string's length. I'm also confused because you mention the string `/home/username`, which `%1~` would never generate.

Comment: @Gotoro And to simplify slightly, you can get the length of the whole prompt via `print -nP "$PS1" | wc -m`

Comment: @Kusalananda Right, a bit of an XY problem, IMHO.  The real question *seems* to be how to get the length of the prompt.  But the question as phrased is how to get the actual output of the `%1~` prompt expansion.  I'm assuming that the reference to `/home/username` is because of an attempt to use `$PWD` or something like that, unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ultimately, I want to get shell-generated string length, yes. Even if I get just the shell's representation, which your first answer provides, that would be fine as I can pipe the resulting characters into some other stuff and get the length. I mention the string ```/home/username``` as that would be underlying path of the ```~``` to just give the context

Comment: @Gotoro please edit your question accordingly, clarifying what it is you need exactly - as in the information you've provided here in comments, etc.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention what you need the string length for to ensure you're not barking up the wrong tree when there's a different and better way to do what you need to do.

Comment: Possibly related: [Zsh prompt filling whole width with user input in next line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250451)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To do prompt expansion other than at the prompt, there's

```
print -rP %1~
```

Or:

```
print -rPv expanded %1~
```

To store in a expanded variable.

Or use the `%` parameter expansion flag:

```
var=%1~
print -r -- ${(%)var}
```

Or to store in a variable:

```
expanded=${(%)var}
```

To get the length in number of characters:

```
length=${#${(%)var}}
```

But note that if there are colouring/bold/italic... directives, the length will also include the number of characters in the colouring escape sequences, you won't get the display width of the prompt expansion.